# Replace a list of numbers from Hive table

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hql

I have a hive table where the data is like this -

[image]

where key is just a unique column and ph1,ph2.. are the phone numbers.
Objective is to replace the popular phone numbers with blank.
I already have a table which contains popular phone numbers.
For this e.g. let us assume that 100 and 50 are the popular phone numbers.
Thus the output should look like this -

[image]

I tried this query but hive doesn't support this -

```
        select 
        case when ph1 in (select phone_no from popular_phone_number)
        then "" end as ph1_masked,
        case when ph2 in (select phone_no from popular_phone_number)
        then "" end as ph2_masked
        from base_table;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `left join` and some `case` logic:

```
select bt.key,
       (case when ppn1.phone_no is not null then null else ph1 end) as ph1,
       (case when ppn2.phone_no is not null then null else ph2 end) as ph2,
       (case when ppn3.phone_no is not null then null else ph3 end) as ph3,
       (case when ppn4.phone_no is not null then null else ph4 end) as ph4
from base_table bt left join
     popular_phone_number ppn1
     on ppn1.phone_no = bt.ph1 left join
     popular_phone_number ppn2
     on ppn2.phone_no = bt.ph2 left join
     popular_phone_number ppn3
     on ppn3.phone_no = bt.ph3 left join
     popular_phone_number ppn4
     on ppn4.phone_no = bt.ph4;
```